# Using Entity Framework for runtime defined metadata

Tags: entity-framework

We are actually analyzing the impact of migrating our current DataBase management system to the Entity Framework. As of today (before the migration), the product gives the ability for the end users to create their own object types within the ASP .Net application from the admin interface. These object types are then translated to DB table creation/deletion/update both for the fields and the tables. Typically, one user can create a new MyCar object type from the end-user interface, create some attributes, and once validated he can then create new values. This is obviously reflected in the database as a new MyCar table, two fields, and new inserts.

The main question I'm having relates to the way Entity Framework can be integrated so that we could as a first step query these tables through Linq queries. I know that ideally we should either use the code-first or the model-first approach but we want to proceed step by step.

After making a few researches it turns out that:

1. The Entity Framework doesn't provide the ability to directly update the internal metadata
2. We could take advantage of the dynamic Type creation so that the Entity Framework would be based on a code-first model (runtime, but still code-first :-)) and the dynamic queyword would allow us to retrieve the attributes through late binding. See this [linq](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/206416/Use-dynamic-type-in-Entity-Framework-4-1-SqlQuery).

Hope that I provided the big picture. Please tell me if I'm missing anything and if the approach described in the second bullet point seems to be the right answer for my problem. One of the challenge is also that fields or types can be created: if I have to go through runtime-created types using reflection I won't be able to do that. In this case I could use appdomains (and recreate a new one whenever I have to do a reset) but this could introduce new issues (accessibility / performance / entity framework incompatiblility with types defined in other appdomains / ...).

I know quite well IQToolkit and I know how I could redefine the metadata at runtime easily without having to introduce .Net types - in this regard IQToolkit could be the prefered solution...

Any suggestion are welcome!

Comment: how are you going to work against the dynamically created types? It would mean that you would have to create all your queries dynamically as well. Also, once you start using a context based on your dynamically created model you won't be able to add any new types (I mean that will not work). I think that once you go down this road everything will be reflection based (slow), dynamic (complicated - especially Linq) very hard to maintain and debug. Also, what would be the benefit of using EF in such a solution?

Comment: Today, we are already working against the dynamically created types by constructing our SQL queries and going through the returned datasets. The idea is providing the possibility of using the Linq power to optimize and simplify the process of creating the SQL statements for simple queries and more complex queries (aggregation queries...).

I agree that in this case everything will be reflection based throug h the dynamic keyword.

I know that EF is wider than just a SQL generator but for now we cannot replace the whole metadata/DB generators.

Comment: If you don't know the types at design time you cannot write Linq queries therefore you need to generate expression trees dynamically. I am not sure if `dynamic` is a silver bullet here. I think you need to create a prototype - just 2 entities - and see if this is going to work.

Comment: We will for sure create a prototype and see the limitations. Turns out that linq query expressions are not allowed over dynamic source type so this will be very likely tricky... and require the usage of heavy expression trees. I will update this post hopefully in a few weeks and share our conclusions...

Comment: This is what I was afraid of - Linq requires types to be known at compile time..